# Error: Failed to lookup view "index"

Tags: node.js, express

I tried following various other threads but none of them helped.
I am trying to render ejs files, using express app. But on listening on the port it show the following error.

Error

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "login"
at Function.app.render (C:\Users\darsh\Desktop\Semester_1\SSDI\Sprint 3\workspace\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:495:17)
at ServerResponse.res.render (C:\Users\darsh\Desktop\Semester_1\SSDI\Sprint 3\workspace\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:756:7)
at C:\Users\darsh\Desktop\Semester_1\SSDI\Sprint 3\workspace\server.js:150:13
at callbacks (C:\Users\darsh\Desktop\Semester_1\SSDI\Sprint 3\workspace\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:161:37)
at param (C:\Users\darsh\Desktop\Semester_1\SSDI\Sprint 3\workspace\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:135:11)
at pass (C:\Users\darsh\Desktop\Semester_1\SSDI\Sprint 3\workspace\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:142:5)
at Router._dispatch (C:\Users\darsh\Desktop\Semester_1\SSDI\Sprint 3\workspace\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:170:5)
at Object.router (C:\Users\darsh\Desktop\Semester_1\SSDI\Sprint 3\workspace\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:33:10)
at next (C:\Users\darsh\Desktop\Semester_1\SSDI\Sprint 3\workspace\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:190:15)
at Object.handle (C:\Users\darsh\Desktop\Semester_1\SSDI\Sprint 3\workspace\node_modules\connect-flash\lib\flash.js:21:5)
at next (C:\Users\darsh\Desktop\Semester_1\SSDI\Sprint 3\workspace\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:190:15)
at SessionStrategy.strategy.pass (C:\Users\darsh\Desktop\Semester_1\SSDI\Sprint 3\workspace\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:338:9)
at SessionStrategy.authenticate (C:\Users\darsh\Desktop\Semester_1\SSDI\Sprint 3\workspace\node_modules\passport\lib\strategies\session.js:75:10)
at attempt (C:\Users\darsh\Desktop\Semester_1\SSDI\Sprint 3\workspace\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:361:16)
at Object.authenticate [as handle] (C:\Users\darsh\Desktop\Semester_1\SSDI\Sprint 3\workspace\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:362:7)
at next (C:\Users\darsh\Desktop\Semester_1\SSDI\Sprint 3\workspace\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:190:15)
```

My File Structure

```
- Workspace
   - client 
      - css
      - js
   - views
      - login.ejs
      - index.ejs
  - server.js
```

Small snippet of Code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
app.set('views', path.resolve(__dirname, '/views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); // set up ejs for templating
app.listen(8080);

    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.render('login.ejs'); // load the login.ejs file
    });


    app.get('/index', function(req, res) {
      res.render('index.ejs')
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this can help. Here, they are giving the complete path to the ejs file.
 https://www.google.co.in/amp/scotch.io/amp/tutorials/use-ejs-to-template-your-node-application

Comment: I followed the example, but it does not resolve the problem.

Comment: Please check my another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use path.join instead of path.resolve,
Because path.resolve will result in `/views`.

Try using path.join(__dirname + '/views').
Do not forget to put const path = require('path').

Comment: Still facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one.

```
var express = require('express')
var http = require('http')
var app = express()
var server = http.createServer(app)
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.listen(8080)

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   res.render('login')
})
```